# stop button,not functioning on audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

In my script i used following codes:

```
<button class="button" id="stopbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').pause(); document.getElementById('myTune').currentTime = 0;"></button>
```

But stream dash board displays,i still connect with stream,because,i used pause methode.so,what i am looking for is completely disconnect from stream after pressing stop button.

`.stop()` method not work

1. [code pen link](https://codepen.io/iflix/pen/pdyazj)  and  [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ftk5fam8/2/)

any clue on this?

Comment: What if you change the source of audio to nothing!

Comment: not work .i tried that too

Comment: What do you mean from not works? Nothing happens? Or streaming is not stopped even if you remove the source address?

Comment: @Ali Sheikhpour ,Hi!,stream stopped.but in dash board it's show's still listeners are connected.,because,i used  pause method as above.so,i am looking for solutions,that completely disconnected listeners from stream after they clicked stop button.hope it's clear now?